# How to search for a key value pair in a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a list(users) with dictionary elements with the following format

```
{'id': 1, 'username': 'abc', 'password':'xyz'}
```

Can I iterate over the list and apply an if condition for username using python's "in" operator using a variable value. Something like

```
user = abc
if user in users:
    do something here
```

I tried using if loop and it works perfectly fine but I wanted to use "in" or any other operator instead. I also tried this:

```
dict = "{\"username\":\"" + "myuser" + "\"}"
if dict in users:
      do something
```

Comment: *I tried using if loop and it works perfectly fine but I wanted to use "in" or any other operator instead.* why? And did it work?

Comment: Do you finally need the user details with the particular `username`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`next`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) operator to get the first matching element in the `users` list:

```
>>> users = [{'id': 1, 'username': 'abc', 'password':'xyz'}, {'id': 2, 'username': 'def', 'password':'zyx'}]

# getting the user with username 'def'
>>> next((user for user in users if user['username'] == 'def'), None)
{'id': 2, 'password': 'zyx', 'username': 'def'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for key, value in dict.iteritems():
    if key=='user':
        if value=='abc':
            //do something
```

Note: For Python 3.x, iteritems() has been replaced with simply items().